# MongoDB Ordering Nullable Types With C# Linq Driver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, sorting, nullable

I'm using the MongoDB C# Linq Driver to order search results for displaying in a list on screen. I'd like to be able to order by columns whose values are nullable, but to always display the null values at the bottom. This is possible using Linq with an in memory collection via the following code:

```
items.OrderByDescending(d => d.AppointmentTime.HasValue).ThenBy(d => d.AppointmentTime);
```

However when I attempt to do this using the MongoDB C# driver I get an exception:

```
NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (d.AppointmentTime.HasValue).
```

I've tried using != null rather than HasValue but this doesn't work either. Is there any way to convince mongo to order by the absence of a value in this way?

**EDIT:** Should have said this is a DateTime? value we're dealing with. I've tried

```
items.OrderByDescending(d => d.AppointmentTime ?? DateTime.MinValue)
```

but this generates a similar NotSupportedException.

Comment: what happens if you try this? `items.OrderByDescending(d => d.AppointmentTime ?? 0)`

Comment: That won't even compile - AppointmentTime is a DateTime object so ?? 0 is comparing DateTime and an int. Sorry, should maybe have made that clear. Incidentally I've tried ?? DateTime.MinValue, same NotSupportedException

Comment: Ah I thought it could have been an int due to the name AppointmentTime. Have you tried items.OrderByDescending(d => d.AppointmentTime) and seen the results without the null check?

Comment: Yeah I've tried - it works the way you'd expect. When you order Descending it goes down in date order with nulls at the bottom (fine) but when you do the inverse and order ascending you get the nulls at the top and the ones with actual values at the bottom - I want the nulls always at the bottom and the results with actual dates ordered either ascending or descending.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can however first query only the null documents and then query the others with an orderBy

Comment: ot all queries can be translated from LINQ to MongoDB. And I think MongoDB has not such a thing like HasValue. In LINQ you can use OfType, but then you would not showing null values. Maybe you can try out with Aggregation Framework.

Comment: Yeah I don't wanna actually exclude the null values, just order them differently. I'm not convinced there's any way I can do this :(

Comment: why not just get all the results first then split them accordingly, reorder them then add the null records back?

Comment: That's kind of an icky hack comparatively speaking. I'd have to run two queries and then join the results for one operation. I guess I may have to do this but it doesn't feel like a great solution.

Comment: Come to that it's not even an icky hack that can be easily implemented in LINQ because Mongo doesn't support the Union operator.

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ statement you are using is actually converted to a query and sent over to `mongod`. The exception you are getting is because `mongod` has no concept of nullable types. If you look at the MongoDB docs (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/), you will notice that `mongod` is only aware that a field is null. But it is only aware that field is null for a document when a query is executed against that field. As such, null fields are always sorted below everything else.

You can execute your sort in `mongod` or you can execute it in memory on the client side. 
To sort using {{mongod}} you should be able to simply:

```
items.Where(x => x.Bar == "foo").ToArray().OrderByDescending(x => x.Widget);
```

To ensure it sorts in memory, the query has to be executed first. This can be done by forcing a `.ToArray()` or something similar. So you can chain all of this together by doing something like:

```
items.Where(x => x.Bar == "foo").ToArray().OrderByDescending(x => x.Widget.HasValue).ThenBy(x => x.Widget.Value);
```

I would advise against an in memory sort on the client side if at all possible. If your where clause is not sufficiently restrictive, you can end up transferring a lot of data across the network to the client. At best, this takes time -- at worst the client crashes from lack of resources.